# Setting a UIImageView programatically causes the UIImageView to move?

Tags: uiimageview, uiimage

Regardless of whether Auto Layout is on, when trying to change the UIImageView inside my Prototype Cell, the ImageView appears to move to a different position as you can see in the design below.

**IB Design:**

[image]

**Simulator:**

[image]

I have added Constraints and set them all to 'Required' and even tried deleting the other content in the Prototype Cell, but this doesn't work either.

What could I be doing wrong?

***Edit***

When I log my constraints, they seem to just be the width and height of the `UIImageView`

```
2012-12-02 15:49:30.313 myApp[7551:c07] Constraints - (
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x80985c0 V:[UIImageView:0x80982d0(80)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x8098600 H:[UIImageView:0x80982d0(160)]>"
)
```

***Edit 2***

When deleting the `UIImageView` altogether, it still produces the same output, i.e. the image in the same position.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so it turn out `UITableViewCell` already has a `UIImageView` named "imageView" and changing my `IBOutlet` to something less generic solved the problem.

*Be sure to check the names don't already exist in the UITableView subclass!*